# Mongo DB connections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Am using Mongoose to connect to MongoDB. Created a pool of 10 connections for a database. I just want to ensure if all the 10 connections are used or only 1 if there are around 1000 concurrent users

1.Is there any unique identifier in the connection object to differentiate which connection is being used ?

sample connection string -

```
mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/mydatabase',{server:{poolSize:10}});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have a connection pool in place, and the default will be so the maximum size is always set upon the first usage of that connection. So by the defaults:

```
poolSize: 5,
minPoolSize: 3
```

That means on initial connection, all 5 connections will be made and set in the pool. Over time as these go idle ( and if they do ) then the pool size will drop to the minimum of 3. Of course neither maximum or minimum strays from these parameters as you have them set.

If you are reasonably busy on activity, then chances are that you will have the maximum number in the pool available as they are being regularly drawn from the pool and are not stale.

You can of course get the current usage information by interrogating the driver information. The connection pool entries are in an array and you can get the count by getting the length of this.

From a mongoose model, the path to get here is:

```
console.log( Model.db.db.serverConfig.connectionPool.openConnections.length );
```

Which digs into the native driver information to get this. There is other interesting information along that path you might find useful for application tooling.

Comment: For a request, how to find out which connection is used from the pool.Is there any unique ID for each connection